# Guzzle Services - Generating an XML element with an attribute and value

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle Services to build an XML request based on given data. I'm having problems generating a tag with an attribute and single value. For example:

```
<foo bar="some value">some other value</foo>
```

I can generate a tag with multiple attributes and no value like this:

```
<foo bar="some value" baz="some other value" />
```

by using the following service description:

```
'parameters' => [
    'foo' => [
        'location' => 'xml',
        'type' => 'object',
        'properties' => [
            'bar' => [
                'location' => 'xml',
                'type' => 'string',
                'data' => ['xmlAttribute' => true]
            ],
            'baz' => [
                'location' => 'xml',
                'type' => 'string',
                'data' => ['xmlAttribute' => true]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Or I can generate a tag with a single attribute and a value that's nested inside another tag, like this:

```
<foo bar="some value">
    <baz>some other value</baz>
</foo>
```

by using the following service description:

```
'parameters' => [
    'foo' => [
        'location' => 'xml',
        'type' => 'object',
        'properties' => [
            'bar' => [
                'location' => 'xml',
                'type' => 'string',
                'data' => ['xmlAttribute' => true]
            ],
            'baz' => [
                'location' => 'xml',
                'type' => "string',
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

But it doesn't seem that there's a way to generate a tag like this:

```
<foo bar="some value">some other value</foo>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just looking through the tests that are there I think not.

Comment: I've also looked through the tests and also noticed there is no test case for this scenario. I've also stepped through the source, and it doesn't seem like it's possible. But I'm hoping I can be proven wrong.

Comment: Well I learned this existed at least ;) Only knew it as an HTTP client.   Must be new... Should comment on the github repo or write a pull request.